# 'rd is not defined' error on Google Maps integration

Tags: html, google-maps, firefox

All the sudden I have this strange error and my Google Maps integration isn't working on Firefox anymore while on Chrome it works perfectly.

This is the code for my map:

```
 var map;
 var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(42.439071, 19.266683);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myCenter
 });

 function initialize() {
   var mapProp = {
     center: myCenter,
     zoom: 14,
     draggable: true,
     scrollwheel: false,
     mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);
   marker.setMap(map);

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.setContent(contentString);
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
   }); 
 };

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", resizeMap());

 $('#myMapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   resizeMap();
 });

 function resizeMap() {
   if (typeof map =="undefined")
     return;

   var center = map.getCenter();
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
   map.setCenter(center); 
 };
```

And I include it like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I get the following error

> rd is not defined
>   https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/17/2/main.js (line 53)

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Here is a JSFiddle to test it:
http://jsfiddle.net/sTLY8/7/

Comment: Your code is not complete: `Uncaught ReferenceError: infowindow is not defined `, then `Uncaught ReferenceError: contentString is not defined`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

After updating my Firefox to Version 30 I have same problems with my Google Maps application:

> ReferenceError: xd is not defined https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/de_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/16/13/main.js line 54 > eval`

It seems Firebug causes these errors and there's already an [issue filed for this](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7471). I disabled the *Script* panel in Firebug and now it works again in Firefox.

Comment: Yes, firebug causes the problem.

Comment: This is due to security reason. Because your google map API is https secured request.

Comment: This might be a good idea, for Security, thanks Firebug, now Clients can't read my script. What's going to stop them from just putting my script `src` into a Browser directly?

Comment: @nebroT Thanks for the awesome answer, wish I would've found it 2 hrs ago after pulling hairs out. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

This is a known platform bug with firebug 2.0 under firefox 30.

Either disable the Firebug script panel or use Firefox 31 beta.

See corresponding

- Firebug issue tracker [link](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7495)
- Mozilla Bugzilla [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1021131)